# Live-action movie or TV show from late 90s/early 00s with kids, a friendly spaceship/thing, and an evil guy

Tags: story-identification

Back in the late 90s/early 00s in the US, I remember seeing a fragment of a show or movie on TV (don't remember the channel), the scene in question taking place in a industrial area, apparently at night and/or obscured by fog; there was a spaceship or something, but all that could be seen of it were bright lights overhead (large ones, not just point sources), and there were some kids who were trying to keep some evil guy from doing something to the ship/creature (stealing it, taking control of it?). The kids called it (or its occupant) by name, having apparently befriended it, but I unfortunately cannot remember the name they used (otherwise I probably wouldn't have had to ask this question).

The kids may have been middle-school age, possibly younger, but I'm not sure. There was at least one girl and one boy, possibly more. I don't remember the lights flickering or strobing; they stayed a constant white (there may have been some lights of different colors, but I only remember white).

The industrial area was outdoors; something like a really big electrical substation, perhaps?

Comment: Do you remember which channel/country you saw this on? Or the colour of the lights (all white, or a mixture?). What about the kids – how old, what gender, etc.? The more details you can provide, the more likely you are to get an answer. =)

Comment: @alexwlchan Added some more detail as I remember more.

Comment: This reminds me of an old Disney flick called *The Cat From Outer Space*, but [the plot synopsis on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_from_Outer_Space) doesn't seem to match up, so maybe not.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't seem to match up. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it may have been Animorphs. The first episode they find the alien in a construction zone. I belive the show is on Netflix right now.

(the scene starts at about 7min in in that link.)

Comment: It's not Animorphs, unfortunately. I'm pretty sure the kids were younger than that.

Comment: I'm not sure there is enough info to hunt this one down.